# Why does SQL COUNT return a list?

Tags: python, sql, cs50, finance, stock

I'm trying to figure out if some user has shares of a specific stock, if he doesn't, I want to insert that he just bought that stock into my SQL table, however if he already owned that stock I want to update the amount of shares he has of that stock. To find out whether he owns any shares of that stock I user the count command provided by SQL.

```
count = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(shares) FROM user_stocks WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", user_id, symbol)
        if count == 0:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO user_stocks (user_id, symbol, shares) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", user_id, symbol, shares)
        else:
            count = count + shares
            db.execute("UPDATE user_stocks SET shares = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", count, user_id, symbol)
```

However an error occurs when I try to update count and it says:
File "/workspaces/43335819/pset9/finance/app.py", line 75, in buy
count = count + shares
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

When I read the documentation on COUNT, it said that the command returns an integer but it seems that it returns a list. How do I fix this problem?

I tried doing

`count = int(db.execute("SELECT COUNT(shares) FROM user_stocks WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", user_id, symbol))`

but that didn't work because for int() to work it needs to be a string or a float.

Comment: Please add the link to the documentation of the `execute` method. We don't even know what your `db` is.

Comment: Note there is a [dedicated cs50 stack exchange site](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/). It's currently beta but seems fairly active.

Answer (score 0):

From [Hints in the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/9/finance/#hints) [emphasis added]

> Within cs50.SQL is an execute method whose first argument should be a str of SQL. If that str contains question mark parameters to which values should be bound, those values can be provided as additional named parameters to execute. See the implementation of login for one such example. The return value of execute is as follows:
>
> - **If str is a SELECT, then execute returns a list of zero or more dict objects, inside of which are keys and values representing a
>   table’s fields and cells, respectively.**
> - If str is an INSERT, and the table into which data was inserted contains an autoincrementing PRIMARY KEY, then execute returns the value of the newly inserted row’s primary key.
> - If str is a DELETE or an UPDATE, then execute returns the number of rows deleted or updated by str.

Answer (score -2):

What is the problem in the line below?

```
count = count + shares
```

- `count` is an integer
- `shares` is a list

You can not concat an integer to a list.

A possible solution

```
count = count + len(shares)
```

With the line above, you deal with 2 integers since `len(shares)` return an int

Comment: When you do `0 + []`, do you get their error message?

Comment: And if `count` is an integer, why did `int(count)` not work?

Comment: @KellyBundy Try to run `my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_number = 4

result = my_list + my_number `
share the result please.
(when I run it I get :
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list)

Comment: Why should I do that? That's not what your answer says.